# How to remove the numbers inside the source file name in COPY command in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I was writing a docker file to copy some war files in the webapps folder of tomcat container. The war files are contained inside target folder after maven build.

```
ARG BUILD_VERSION=1.0
COPY STUDENT_MANAGER/target/STUDENT-${BUILD_VERSION}/*.war /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

How can I remove the build version and write something like

```
COPY STUDENT_MANAGER/target/STUDENT*/*.war /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

I want to remove the build number as I want to automate the docker build and copy the files irrespective of build version.

Comment: If it's a single file, you could specify the file name on the right-hand side of `COPY`; or you could `RUN mv` in some form to rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest you put your `*.war` in one repository `war-repo` then run:

```
COPY war-repo /opt/tomcat/webapps/
```

which will copy all `*.war` files

or you'll need to enter your files one by one, from docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

```
COPY path1/*1.war path2/*2.war ... /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

Comment: This approach cant be used as per requirement....is their a way of using regex operators

Comment: You can zip and copy the whole repository `STUDENT_MANAGER/target`, then use a bash script with a loop and a `cp` command into `/opt/tomcat/webapps`